# Stripe - Add metadata into connected/destination account while/after creating checkout sessions and payment

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am doing a simple task. Code is already working. Following are the steps:

using this post: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

1. purchasing ticket from UI
2. creating checkout session in the backend and passing requried data. These all is working fine.

   ```
        const session = await this._stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          payment_method_types: ['card'],
          customer_email: email,
          line_items: [
             {
                 price_data: {
                 currency: ###,
                 unit_amount_decimal: ###,
                 product_data: {
                      name: ###,
                      description: ###
                 }    
             },
             quantity: 1
           }
        ],
        payment_intent_data: {
            on_behalf_of: ###,
            transfer_data: {
                destination: ###,
                amount: ###
        },
        metadata,
        statement_descriptor: ###
     },
     mode: 'payment',
     success_url: successUrl,
     cancel_url: cancelUrl
   });
   ```

code is working fine and I am able to get the payment done and it is reflected into my main account with metadata and other fields.

**Issue: I want the same metadata into my connected account where I am transferring money so that we can share the same metadata. There is a metadata section into payment inside the connected/destination account. That's where I want to add those details.
Is there anything else I need to update like charge or transfer or anything? I tried updating transfer but none of them reflected metadata into the destination account.**

Where should I add what params to get metadata into my connected account?
Any help will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When funds are transferred from your platform account to a connected account two objects are created to represent the transfer:

1. A Transfer object (`tr_`) that exists on your platform account
2. A Payment object (`py_`) that exists on the connected account

In the Stripe API Payment objects are a type of Charge, so you can [use the Charges API to add `metadata` to the Payment object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/update#update_charge-metadata).

Note: Payment objects exist on connected accounts, not on your platform account, so you need to [make an API call on behalf of the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication) to access/modify Payment objects.

You can get the Payment object's ID by looking at [the `destination_payment` property on the Transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object#transfer_object-destination_payment).

Comment: The only relevant answer on the internet! +1

Answer (score 1):

After a payment intent is created you can fetch the transfer details with the (tr_) id, this will have the payment id (py_) you need to find the connected accounts charge.

```
def get_charge_transfer(params):
    """
       Get transfer details
    """
    transfer = stripe.Transfer.retrieve(params["tr_id"])
    return transfer
```

After you get the payment id (py_) you can retrieve the charge id by passing the py_ id and connected destination account id to the charge interface to update the charge object on the connected account.

```
import json
def update_connected_charge(event):
    """
      update meta data on connected charge account by payment id
      param: py_id <str> payment id, 
      param: acc_id <str> account id
    """
    params = json.loads(event.get("body", "{}"))
    charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(params['py_id'],stripe_account=params["acc_id"])
    charge.update({ "metadata": { "test": "123" }})
    charge.save()
    return charge
```